# Could not find file 'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=*, PublicKeyToken=6595b64144ccf1df,

Tags: c#, wpf, manifest, common-controls

I'm trying to integrate [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21276/Vista-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator) into my application.

At first it crashed with

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'TaskDialogIndirect' in DLL 'ComCtl32'.
```

so I uncommented

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
    />
</dependentAssembly>
```

as was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719251/unable-to-find-an-entry-point-named-taskdialogindirect-in-dll-comctl32).

Now the application won't compile with the following message:

```
Could not find file 'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=*, 
    PublicKeyToken=6595b64144ccf1df, ProcessorArchitecture=*, Type=win32'
```

Deleting  app.manifest causes the app to crash, because I'm using Microsoft Ribbon.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: With what version of Windows you're trying to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file you are trying is not supported on Windows 7.  This means you would have to supply it, if your trying to develop an application that works on Windows XP, simplest solution is to drop support for Windows XP.

> Mainstream Support for Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 ended on March 31,
>   2005. However, we are releasing this non-security related package because it contains improvements that were ready for release just
>   prior to the end of Mainstream Support. Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 has
>   transitioned to Extended Support which runs through March 31, 2008.
>   Microsoft is not extending the Mainstream Support phase for Microsoft
>   Visual Basic 6.0 in any way.

**Source:** [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Common Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10019)

> Supported operating systems: Windows 2000, Windows 2000 Advanced
>   Server, Windows 2000 Professional Edition , Windows 2000 Server,
>   Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows NT, Windows
>   Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows XP Home Edition , Windows XP Media
>   Center Edition, Windows XP Professional Edition, Windows XP Tablet PC
>   Edition

Until you stop using this file, it cannot be run as a 64-bit process, on any Windows operating system including the 64-bit Windows XP Edition.

There is no reason you could not modify the behavior of the code you want to use to supported files.

You might have better luck with this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137552/WPF-TaskDialog-Wrapper-and-Emulator

Comment: You may be right about the Visual Basic 6 wrapper of the Common Controls. The TaskDialogs introduced in Windows Vista and featured prominently by Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 are indeed implemented in the ComCtl32.dll. See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

Comment: I meant: However, the TaskDialogs introduced in Windows Vista and featured prominently by Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 are indeed implemented in the ComCtl32.dll. Therefore it is still fully supported and it will be around for a very long time. See also msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/…. –  janm 11 hours ago   delete

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same error message in a project, and just wanted to share my solution.

I was building a project on Windows 7, and the project had a dependency upon this dll listed in the manifest file. Since it was trying to compile on Windows 7, it could not find the file, and hence I got the same error.

The solution was simply to remove this dependency from the manifest, as nothing in the project actually seemed to be relying on this assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to the question, but related to the same error message.

I tried to publish a WPF app via the Right-click on the project -> Publish and the app stopped compiling afterwards.

The only way to make it work normally was to remove all added lines in the project (csproj) file.