# Impossible to publish CefSharp.MinimalExample on Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cefsharp

I'd like to publish the sample application [CefSharp.MinimalExample](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) (Make a .exe file) With visual studio 2015 by following this : Debug - CefSharpMinimal.Example.WinForm properties - Publish now and I still get the follwing error:

> Could not find file 'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=*, PublicKeyToken=6595b64144ccf1df, ProcessorArchitecture=*, Type=Win32'.

As I did not edit anything in the source code, provided by the Sample App, I don't understand what is wrong
[image]

Comment: The error is about a reference file not found in your PC, but the Win32 processor architecture doesn't look like a valid architecture. Anyhow, it seems someone's already had the [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330105/could-not-find-file-microsoft-windows-common-controls-version-6-0-0-0-culture) as yours.

Comment: Avoid using clickonce if you can. Try the squirrel Windows installer. If you remove that app manifest entry tooltips won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and I fixed it by removing or commenting this lines in the file **app.mainfiest** (in project where you see error):

```
  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->

  <!--<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>-->
```